# "could not generate value" for a safe it knows i made

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am experiencing a problem whereby safes that are made on chain are recognized, the events decoded, but the safe is somehow still not completely set up, because the API endpoint says it's not there.

https://gateway.safe.shyft.network/cgw/v1/chains/11437/safes/0xE065dC1371B1eA766337fbAD50752F458e989BaD
-> "could not generate value"

https://gateway.safe.shyft.network/txs/api/v1/safes/0xE065dC1371B1eA766337fbAD50752F458e989BaD/creation/ -> appears to be a healthy record

http://gateway.safe.shyft.network/txs/api/v1/safes/0xE065dC1371B1eA766337fbAD50752F458e989BaD/ -> shows owners as null ?

The database shows the expected setup transactions in history_internaltx but there is no corresponding row in the decoded table.

Watching database transactions, the list of "almost updated" contracts is steadily lengthening.

Running most recent release of upstream forks as of Monday.

What am I missing?

[Originating contract call](http://bx.testnet.shyft.network/tx/0x9a84bf9c5ca771dae0290800b53d47f538c8b51a77d8cadba0db9ba990561ced/logs)

Comment: Hi! Could you share the tx service API url to debug the issue? (currently you are only sharing the gateway)

Comment: Certainly - `https://rpc.testnet.shyft.network/` chain ID 11437.  I will follow up with a faucet - or can serve as one.

Comment: Thanks. It would be very useful that you add the code for the contracts on http://bx.testnet.shyft.network/, so we can debug what's happening. Also, you can officialy deploy the contracts on your chain following https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments and creating a PR

Comment: I published those contracts.
We are running very close to stock installation of safe-infrastructure, specifying the latest version of all gnosis images. We have a customized react frontend at https://safe.shyft.network/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/s9TPnM3b shows before and after in a postgresql database dump, showing the partially processed "safe setup" transaction.   These can be seen online at https://gateway.safe.shyft.network/txs/api/v1/safes/0xc5847FcB4A4270DC77800a1487Ce29cB9922bD41/creation/ .  These correspond to line 77 of the pastebin.    I am working through all the celery processes to understand which one is supposed to update the list of owners, nonce, version #.

Comment: Compare with a well-formed transaction gateway response https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/0xe8b541b0E9a3981E3aC0e324B987940c4eF4069B/